# How to avoid last three digits from converting to zero in excel

Tags: unix, plsql

I have a shell script, in which it connects to db and extracts the data into .CSV file. but when i downloaded the file and opened in excel it is appending zeros to last three digits of a column, because the column has 18 digits, but excel can support only upto 15 for number, is there any way that I can change my logic in shell script so when opening in excel doesn't show last three digits as zeros

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Code and sample data would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A number that contains more than 15 digits in Excel, it changes any digits past the fifteenth place to zeros. You can cast the column values to string on export.

```js
// Use customizeData
 
exportOptions: {
    //--
},
customizeData: function (data) {
    // This code is to find the column name's index which you want to cast.
    var ind = data.header.indexOf("ColumnName"); 
    
    for (var i = 0; i < data.body.length; i++) {
        // will cast the number to string.
        data.body[i][ind] = '\u200C' + data.body[i][ind]; 
    }
}
```

Error_Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to look data in Excel, you must put number data in text format. So, Excel doesn't try to convert it to number. To do so, put numbers in CSV file as below

```
="123123123123123123123";="123123123123123123123"
```